# Putting text on a border with css html

Tags: html, css

How can i hide border behind MON and give some space like in this pic

https://www.screencast.com/t/SJmg63NZuF

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

h2 {
  width: 50px;
  margin-top: -15px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h2>MON</h2>
  <p>7am - yeah</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're trying to achieve this. The convention of using `<legend>` tags which is a child of `<fieldset>` is usually applied and used for forms but you can achieve the same as shown below. I tweaked the code a bit and added a background to show you how you may achieve what you're looking for as the screenshot you posted.
Hope, it helps.

```css
body {
  background-image: url("https://ak9.picdn.net/shutterstock/videos/21522739/thumb/1.jpg");
}

fieldset {
  width: 100px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  text-align: center;
}


h2 {
  color: white;
}

p {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend align="center">
    <h2>MON</h2>
  </legend>
  <p>7am - yeah</p>
  <p>8am - yeah</p>
  <p>9am - yeah</p>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: how can i make MON in center and spacing equal both side of MON

Comment: Oh, you want it centered? Let me tweak the code a bit.

Comment: I have updated the code, just use the attribute of legend i.e align="center" and remove the width from the h2 CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you just need to set the background color from transparent.

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  background: white;
}

h2 {
  width: 50px;
  margin-top: -15px;
  margin-left: 8px;
  padding: 0 14px 0 10px;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h2>MON</h2>
  <p>7am - yeah</p>
</div>
```

Comment: If you use a background image on the body and the div is transparent, the h2 will have an ugly looking white background on top of it.